# Why is my node database query not working

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

new at ndoe and mysql interactions, I am trying to get the data of a collunm in my query, what I've done so far:
groupmemberlist is an array of arrays that I am looping in to get each of the values.

%%EDIT%%

I have add these changes but still only get undefined on my variables:

```
    for (var m = 0; m < groupmemberlist.length; m++) {
                var imgreturned = findpicture(groupmemberlist[m], returnimage);
                console.log(imgtag);
            }
```

This loop can the function findpicture that is:

```
   function returnimage(imgid) {
                imgtag = '<img href="/uploads/' + imgid[0].User_Profile_Photo + ">";

            }

            function findpicture(id, callback) {
                return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                    db.query('SELECT User_Profile_Photo FROM users WHERE id = ?', [id], function (error, results, fields) {
                        if (error) {
                            throw error;
                        } else {
                            imgFromId = results;
                        }
                        callback(imgFromId);
                    });
                })
            }
```

the error that I get is (repeat 4 times):

```
Query {
  domain: null,
  _events:
   { error: [Function],
     packet: [Function],
     end: [Function],
     timeout: [Function],
     'start-tls': [Function] },
  _eventsCount: 5,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  _callback: [Function],
  _callSite: Error
    at Protocol._enqueue (C:\Users\yvyma.DESKTOP-74AK6UQ\Desktop\Nodeapp\express-cc\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Connection.query (C:\Users\yvyma.DESKTOP-74AK6UQ\Desktop\Nodeapp\express-cc\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:200:25)
    at findpicture (C:\Users\yvyma.DESKTOP-74AK6UQ\Desktop\Nodeapp\express-cc\routes\index.js:210:31)
    at Query.<anonymous> (C:\Users\yvyma.DESKTOP-74AK6UQ\Desktop\Nodeapp\express-cc\routes\index.js:232:35)
    at Query.<anonymous> (C:\Users\yvyma.DESKTOP-74AK6UQ\Desktop\Nodeapp\express-cc\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:502:10)
    at Query._callback (C:\Users\yvyma.DESKTOP-74AK6UQ\Desktop\Nodeapp\express-cc\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:468:16)
    at Query.Sequence.end (C:\Users\yvyma.DESKTOP-74AK6UQ\Desktop\Nodeapp\express-cc\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:83:24)
    at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (C:\Users\yvyma.DESKTOP-74AK6UQ\Desktop\Nodeapp\express-cc\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:139:8)
    at Query.EofPacket (C:\Users\yvyma.DESKTOP-74AK6UQ\Desktop\Nodeapp\express-cc\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:123:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\Users\yvyma.DESKTOP-74AK6UQ\Desktop\Nodeapp\express-cc\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:278:23),
  _ended: false,
  _timeout: undefined,
  _timer: Timer { _object: [Circular], _timeout: null },
  sql: 'SELECT User_Profile_Photo FROM users WHERE id = 6 ',
  values: [ 6 ],
  typeCast: true,
  nestTables: false,
  _resultSet: null,
  _results: [],
  _fields: [],
  _index: 0,
  _loadError: null,
  _connection:
   Connection {
     domain: null,
     _events: {},
     _eventsCount: 0,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     config:
      ConnectionConfig {
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 3306,
        localAddress: undefined,
        socketPath: undefined,
        user: 'root',
        password: undefined,
        database: 'express-cc',
        connectTimeout: 10000,
        insecureAuth: false,
        supportBigNumbers: false,
        bigNumberStrings: false,
        dateStrings: false,
        debug: undefined,
        trace: true,
        stringifyObjects: false,
        timezone: 'local',
        flags: '',
        queryFormat: undefined,
        pool: undefined,
        ssl: false,
        multipleStatements: false,
        typeCast: true,
        maxPacketSize: 0,
        charsetNumber: 33,
        clientFlags: 455631,
        protocol41: true },
     _socket:
      Socket {
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: [Object],
        _parent: null,
        _host: null,
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 5,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        _bytesDispatched: 151,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: null,
        _server: null,
        _idleTimeout: -1,
        _idleNext: null,
        _idlePrev: null,
        _idleStart: 9257,
        _destroyed: false,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 44,
        [Symbol(bytesRead)]: 0,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 47,
        [Symbol(triggerAsyncId)]: 10 },
     _protocol:
      Protocol {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 6,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        readable: true,
        writable: true,
        _config: [Object],
        _connection: [Circular],
        _callback: null,
        _fatalError: null,
        _quitSequence: null,
        _handshake: true,
        _handshaked: true,
        _ended: false,
        _destroyed: false,
        _queue: [Array],
        _handshakeInitializationPacket: [Object],
        _parser: [Object] },
     _connectCalled: true,
     state: 'authenticated',
     threadId: 767 } }
```

I also try say var imgname = (results[0].User_Profile_Photo) inside the query function and try console.log the var imgname but it return error of var undefined.

Comment: Try `var imgname = results[0].user_profile_photo;`. MySQL may be downcasing the column names it returns. Or, try `console.log(fields);` to see a description of the fields (columns) in the result set.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is all kinds of messed up. You have some things out of place. Here's a better, though not perfect, version:

```
function findpicture(id) {
  let imgFromId;

  db.query('SELECT User_Profile_Photo FROM users WHERE id = ?', [id], function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) {
      throw error;
    }

    imgFromId = results;
    console.log(imgfromid);
  });
}
```

Now, lets explain what's wrong with your code. It'll provide you some good concepts to understand.

`db.query` is using a callback function. This means that its an `asyncronous` request. That means that the results take some time to come back. What you're trying to do right now by assigning `db.query` to `imgFromId` is not getting the results of your query, but just assigning a reference to whatever comes back from `db.query`.

In the corrected version I shared, you need to define `imgFromId` outside of the callback function. When the results return, you assign the results to that inside the callback function.

However, this will still not fix your issue. Since you're dealing with asyncronous code you need to look into Promises and async/await.

Comment: I understand, but I am still struggling with it, what I have so far now: